# sketch the region of triple integral and express it in the five other possible orders

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Sketch the region of the triple integral
$$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{y} \int_0^{x}  x^2yz dzdxdy$$

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1\!\! \int_{0}^{y}\!\! \int_0^{x} \! x^2yz \:dz\:dx\:dy&=\int_{0}^1\!\! y\int_{0}^{y}\!\!  x^2\left(\int_0^{x} \!z \:dz\right)dx\:dy
\\&=\int_{0}^1\!\! y\int_{0}^{y}\!\!  x^2\times \frac{x^2}2dx\:dy
\\&=\frac12\int_{0}^1\!\! y\int_{0}^{y}\!\! x^4\:dx\:dy
\\&=\frac12\int_{0}^1\!\! y\times \frac{y^5}5\:dy
\\&=\frac1{10} \left[ \frac{y^7}7\right]_{0}^1
\\&=\frac1{70}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I just need help with the sketch